# Type Casting in ReleaseDataCallback()

Tags: ios, opencv, objective-c++, object-detection

I am currently learning using openCv to do object detection on IOS, and I meet with a type casting problem.

below is the code:

```
#pragma mark - Image processing


static void ReleaseDataCallback(void  *info, const void *data, size_t size)
{
#pragma unused(data)
#pragma unused(size)
IplImage *iplImage = info; //here does not work, the xcode show me that "cannot Initialize a variable of type 'IplImage *' (aka '_IplImage *') with an value of type of void *"
cvReleaseImage(&iplImage);
}
```

Maybe a stupid question~ but i did search a lot place but cannot find a solution for the problem.

I found a website :

http://www.kobold2d.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=919981
I tried the suggestion but it does not work)

Comment: Did you try type casting `IplImage *iplImage = (IplImage  *)info;`

Comment: did tried, it does not work. and give me even more errors.  Also I tried (__bridge IplImage*)info, it does not work neither.

Comment: What I see here is that `IplImage` is a struct and type casting it from `void*` to `IplImage *` should be fine. Bridging is only needed when you are converting Objectivc-C object (NSObject or it's subclasses) to c pointer type or vice-verca.

Comment: Oh~I guess you are right~I did it and then I got 30  Apple Mach-O linker Error "_cvReleaseImageHeader", referenced from:

Comment: Best of luck with compiler errors :) and just let me know when you're done

Comment: Really appreciate it!~it seems that this linker error happened to Xcode6.1 and many people fixed it by deleting the DerivedData folder in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, but it does not work for me , mybe it has something to do with that I have updated the xcode to 6.2!~?

Comment: This problem is a linker error and it comes when the linker is not able to link your file with the compiled one (file in framework or other file). You might have to see if you have linked all your binaries correctly. You also need to check if your binary is compiled with the architecture that you're compiling. There is no fixed solution to it you just have to try out each solution. `Tip : ` please read whole the error you might get some idea from that. http://i.imgur.com/SAeckuv.png?1

Comment: I guess this show the problem:       ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/admin/Downloads/iOS-OpenCV-master/opencv2.framework/opencv2, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/admin/Downloads/iOS-OpenCV-master/opencv2.framework/opencv2 (3 slices)        so it is because the openCV framework that i am using does not support arm64 architecture

Comment: might be, try running your code in iPhone 5 or 4

Comment: It builds successfully in Iphone5

Comment: Then it's not compiled for `arm64`, I suggest you to get that binary because apple is not accepting builds which doesn't support 64 bit architecture